# Is it possible to route AVAssetWriter to a network stream in iOS4?

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, ios4, avassetwriter

AVAssetWriter takes a file URL as an argument and writes buffers appended to its AVAssetWriterInput to that file.

```
AVAssetWriter* assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc]
    initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"...fileURL..."]
    fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4
    error:&error];
```

If a network URL is specified (i.e. RTSP - a server expecting a live streaming source), an exception is thrown as a file-based URL is required.

Is there another way of accessing the asset writer output?  I want to take advantage of the integrated H.264 encoding and just access the encoded data bit by bit to stream it over the network.

Comment: As you have found out you must write it to a file. I have written code that streams H.264/AAC in real time over RTP using the iPhone. It uses the H.264 encoder chip on the iphone and does not use private API's, so at the very least you now know it is possible.

Comment: you big tease! are you parsing the H.264 stream from the AVC data in MPEG4 mdat atom?

Comment: @Rhythmic Fistman: You looked at my post history did you? I think you have your answer! For the most part parsing is what I am doing. There are some other things that need to be done to insure the decoder knows what to do with the frames. With some creative C coding it can be done in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Capture the raw samples instead.

Comment: could you provide some directions on how to do what you suggest -- that is, on how to get raw samples out of AV without writing them to disk? :-)

Comment: In short, one can't get h264 frames with `AVFoundation`. Thanks!

Comment: You can, but only using a software encoder on the raw frames.